# Pythonic way to assign labels based on percentile of values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda, pandas-groupby

I want to know what's a good way to approach solving the following problem I have.

I have a python dataframe containing 3 pre-calculated values associated to an ID. I want to assign a label to that ID based on the percentile associated to the value corresponding to one of the calculated columns

given data :

```
### note : VAL1 is a rank i.e lower the better
###.       VAL2 is just a number associated to the ID where the higher the number the better. Assume VAL2 min = 0, max = 25000
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [132, 444, 323], "VAL1": [0.82, 0.16, 0.48], "VAL2": [24000, 6242, 16824]})
    #     ID      VAL1     VAL2
    # 0   132     0.82     24000
    # 1   444     0.16     6242
    # 2   323     0.48     16824
```

desired output :

```
output_df = 
    #     ID      VAL1     VAL2     VAL1_LABEL     VAL2_LABEL
    # 0   132     0.82     24000    bottom50%      top25%
    # 1   444     0.16     6242     top25%         bottom50%
    # 2   323     0.48     16824    middle25-50%   middle25-50%
```

Comment: `pd.qcut(df.VAL1,[0,.25,.50,1])
` ?

Comment: I was unaware of this function, let me check it out but from first glance it seems to do what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign it like

```
df['VAL1_LABEL'] = pd.qcut(df.VAL1,[0,.5,.75,1], labels=['bottom25%','middle25%-50%','top25%']) 
Out[199]: 
0       top25%
1    bottom25%
2    bottom25%
Name: VAL1, dtype: category
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell in your question, this is close to what you're looking for:

```
#take 1-the proportion to get the inverse that you want
df["VAL1_LABEL"] = 1 - df.VAL1/sum(df.VAL1)
df["VAL1_LABEL"] = np.where(df.VAL1_LABEL<df.VAL1_LABEL.mean(),"bottom50%","top50%")
```

You can further specify into it by adding nested conditions.